# Getting values of a matrix inside mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to add a variable to a data frame so that each entry of this variable is picked from an external object (i.e. not a variable of the data frame) according to entries in existing variables of the data frame.

In particular, I have a matrix `param` containing parameter samples (rows) for different TOOLs (columns) and I have a data frame `scenario_tab` storing variables (including seed and TOOL) for different scenarios (rows). I now want to create a new variable `parameter` in that data containing the right parameter for each scenario by picking values from the matrix `param` according to the seed and TOOL entry for each scenario.

Here is an example:

```
# create data frame
Nseeds <- 10
scenarios <- list(
  TOOL = c('R', 'T', 'P'),
  seed = 1:Nseeds
)
scenario_tab <- expand.grid(scenarios)

# create matrix
param <- data.frame(matrix(data=NA, nrow=Nseeds, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c('R', 'T', 'P'))))
param[,'R'] <- rnorm(Nseeds,1,1)
param[,'T'] <- rnorm(Nseeds,0,1)
param[,'P'] <- rnorm(Nseeds,2,1)
```

I think what I want should be possible with mutate from dply, something like:

```
scenario_tab <- mutate(scenario_tab, parameter = param[seed,TOOL])
```

Mutate apparently finds `param` in the environment (However, I don't know how exactly.), but just adds 30 variables of the form `parameter.seed.TOOL`. How can I tell it to pick the single entries?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need to see your two input datasets (at least in part) and your expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. This actually made me recognise that passing wasn't really the problem (though, I don't know how mutate looks for objects in the environment), but picking only single entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a simpler example of what you're trying to achieve:

```
mat <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2, ncol=2)

# try to populate a new column from the values of a matrix, indexed by vs and am
# fails
dplyr::mutate(mtcars, newcol=mat[vs+1, am+1])
```

This doesn't work because matrix indexing can be tricky. In this case, what you want is to index using *another* matrix:

```
dplyr::mutate(mtcars, newcol=mat[cbind(vs+1, am+1)])

#                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb newcol
# Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      3
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      3
# Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      4
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      2
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2      1
# Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      2
...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to merge two data sets, try using left_join() or full_join()

```
left_join(data.frame1, data.frame2, by = c(id1, id2,...))
```